# Show that the matrices form a group. Find an isomorphism of G with a more familiar group of order 6

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that the matrices

$$\left[\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\end{matrix}\right], \left[\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 0&1&0\end{matrix}\right], \left[\begin{matrix}0&1&0\\ 1&0&0\\ 0&0&1\end{matrix}\right], \left[\begin{matrix}0&0&1\\ 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\end{matrix}\right], \left[\begin{matrix}0&0&1\\ 0&1&0\\ 1&0&0\end{matrix}\right], \left[\begin{matrix}0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 1&0&0\end{matrix}\right]$$

form a group. Find an isomorphic of G with a more familiar group of order 6.

How do i prove that matrices are groups? would i find the det? or let a matrice be called A and assume things and try and prove it?

Comment: Can you identify the identity element in this case? How about finding the order of the rest of the elements

Comment: Use the definition of the group. Matrix multiplication is associative, the identity matrix is already in, and you need to prove that every one of those six matrices has an inverse in the same set of 6 matrices. Finally, can you see how multiplication of a column matrix $\left[\begin{matrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{matrix}\right]$ by those matrices changes this column - it permutes $a$, $b$ and $c$, so it looks plausible that your group of matrices is the same as (i.e. isomorphic to) the group of permutations $S_3$. Now try to rigorously prove it by writing the isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These elements form a subgroup of $G=GL_3(\mathbb{F}_2)$, because with $a,b\in G$ also $ab\in G$, and with $a\in G$ also $a^{-1}\in G$. Since there is only one non-abelian group of order $6$, it must be isomorphic to $S_3$. This can be also seen directly, since the matrices correspond to $id, (12), (23), (123),\ldots $, compare the order of the elements.

Comment: How did you get the matrices correspond to id, (12), (23), (123)...

Comment: The second matrix has order $2$, so it must be $(12)$, $(13)$ or $(23)$. The fourth matrix has order $3$, so it must be $(123)$ or $(132)$, with inverse the sixth matrix $(132)$ or $(123)$. Now multiply these matrices and see how it corresponds to multiplication of the permutations.